# How to apply the chain rule for partial derivatives to transformations?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, transformation, partial-derivative

I'm currently working to solve the Black-Scholes model partial differential equation (it's a model for a.o. stock option prices). The Black-Scholes equation for a calloption C(S,t) is given by

$  \frac{∂C}{∂t}+\frac{1}{2} σ^2 S^2  \frac{∂^2 C}{∂S^2}+rS \frac{∂C}{∂S}-rC=0$

S is the stock price and t is time to expiration.

I am solving the equation by transforming it to the heat equation. I am having a little trouble with the first few transformation. The transformations are:

1. $x=ln⁡(\frac{S}{K})$ which gives   $S=Ke^x$
2. $τ=\frac{σ^2}{2} (T-t)$   which gives  $t=T-\frac{2τ}{σ^2}$

The function becomes:

3. $U(x,τ)= \frac{1}{K} C(S,t)=\frac{1}{K} C(Ke^x,T-  \frac{2τ}{σ^2})$

These transformation applied to the partial differential equation above gives the following outcomes for the different terms. I found the following solution on the internet, my problem is that I don't really understand what they do here:

$\frac{∂C}{∂t}=K \frac{∂U}{∂τ}  \frac{∂τ}{∂t}=\frac{-Kσ^2}{2} \frac{∂U}{∂τ},$

$\frac{∂C}{∂S}=K \frac{∂U}{∂x} \frac{∂x}{∂S}=\frac{K}{S}  \frac{∂U}{∂x}=e^{-x}  \frac{∂U}{∂x},$

$\frac{∂^2 C}{∂S^2}=\frac{-K}{S^2}   \frac{∂U}{x}+\frac{K}{S} \frac{∂}{∂S} (\frac{∂U}{∂x})$
$=\frac{-K}{S^2}  \frac{∂U}{∂x}+\frac{K}{S} \frac{∂}{∂x} (\frac{∂U}{∂x}) \frac{∂x}{∂S}$
$=\frac{-K}{S^2}   \frac{∂U}{∂x}+\frac{K}{S^2} \frac{∂^2 U}{∂x^2}$
$=\frac{e^{-2x}}{K} (\frac{∂^2 U}{∂x^2} \frac{-∂U}{∂x}$)

Can someone help me out? I would really appreciate it!!!!

thanks in advance

edit: I now understand the first two but the third is a lot harder.